# Pagination getting slower while page number increasing

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I have a table look like this.

```
parent   VARCHAR PK
priority INT     PK
child    VARCHAR
```

Now I need to SELECT/COUNT, for Spring pagination, those who has children more than specified number.

Here comes my queries.

```sql
-- SELECT
SELECT
  parent,
  GROUP_CONCAT(child ORDER BY priority SEPARATOR 0x1D) AS concatenated_children,
  COUNT(child) AS child_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY parent
HAVING child_count >= ?1
ORDER BY parent ASC
LIMIT 2048,?   -- GETTING SLOWER when the OFFSET is increases
```

```sql
-- COUNT
SELECT COUNT(wrk.parent)
FROM (SELECT parent, COUNT(child) AS child_count
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY parent
      HAVING child_count >= ?1) AS wrk
```

The `?1` part is a constant(`8`) and the the offset part(`,?`) is increases per pagination.

The problem is that the selection query is getting slower while the page number increases.

```
?size=2048,page=0   took 60 ms
?size=2048,page=100 took 2646 ms
```

How can I fix this?

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `parent` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `child` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent`,`priority`)
)
```

```
parent child           priority
---------------------------------
NIKE   Air Max         1
NIKE   Air Jordan      2
WATCH  Patek Philippe  1
WATCH  Rolex           2
```

Criteria

```
Select all parents (and its children)
which each has at least some number children, say 8.
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` shows a lot more information of the table structure so it would help if you can post them. It would also help if you can provide the execution plan of the query.

Comment: @FanoFN updated.

Comment: "PRIMARY KEY (`parent`,`priority`)" -- This allows one parent to show up multiple times; was that really intended?

Comment: @RickJames Yes they are, I believe. Those children(`child`) in a same `parent` should be ordered by  unique `priority`.

Comment: @JinKwon - `priority` represents "first born", "second born", etc.?  (That is, "first to be sold", etc?)

Comment: @RickJames Exactly!

Comment: Having 2048 things on a single web page; having 100+ pages for someone to page through is very tedious. Might there be a better way to help the user get into this massive list?

Comment: @RickJames Good point. But it's not for end users but for an Elasticsearch guy.

Comment: @JinKwon - If you are dumping the whole table via Offset, 100*51 "pages" need to be read.  Dumping via "remember where you left off" takes only 100 pages.  See my answer.

Comment: BTW in "LIMIT 2048,?   -- GETTING SLOWER when the OFFSET is increases" 2048 is the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowdown happens because of the way `OFFSET` works: it fetches all the data and only then drops the part before the offset. For your case it means the grouping will happen not only for the current page, but for all the previous pages too.

The standard trick to fix this kind of problem is to use [Keyset Pagination](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-seek-keyset-pagination/). When fetching the page, you need to remember its last `parent`. Then in order to fetch the next page, you use your query with the

```sql
WHERE parent > YOUR_LAST_PARENT
```

clause and no `OFFSET`. The RDBMS will see that `parent` is indexed and quickly navigate the index to the correct `parent`.

**Full query**:

```sql
  SELECT parent,
         GROUP_CONCAT(child ORDER BY priority
                            SEPARATOR 0x1D) AS concatenated_children,
         COUNT(child) AS child_count
    FROM mytable
   WHERE parent > ?1
GROUP BY parent
  HAVING child_count >= ?2
ORDER BY parent
   LIMIT 2048
```

When querying for the first page, you'll need to run this query without the `WHERE` clause.

Your URL parameters will now look like

```
?size=2048,parent=PARENTXXX
```

Of course, you'll have to give up on Spring Data JPA built-in pagination. It's also not immediately possible to jump to a particular page, you're basically limited to the next/previous pages (as long as you remember the previous page `parent`).

By the way, when experimenting with this I observed that the major problem with the Spring Data JPA pagination is that it has to `COUNT` all the rows. For InnoDB that alone takes more time than fetching the page.

**EDIT**. The first version of the answer recommended adding the condition on `parent` to the `HAVING` clause. As mentioned in the comments below it won't work (I tested that it doesn't work).

Comment: Your link refers to non-MySQL code.  In most cases, MySQL does not use indexes in the `HAVING` clause; it is too late.

Comment: Seems like the `HAVING` is still needed -- since `child_count` is an aggregate.  And the `OFFSET` goes away but the limit stays.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, `OFFSET` must get and toss all the rows before the desired ones.

If you can code the query to "remember where you left off", there is a much faster way than using `OFFSET`.

Here is a MySQL-specific discussion of such:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination